# Create the column with right mapping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame df1 with one of the columns being "values". It looks like -

```
values
['acd3f','rt5gh8','5ty7e']
['rt5gh8','t67ui']
```

I have another dataframe df2 which contains two columns '0' and '1', with values like -

```
0         1
acd3f    I am cool
rt5gh8   I am not cool
5ty7e    ok_sir
t67ui    no_sir
```

I want to modify df1 to add a new column "value_names", which should look like -

```
values                        value_names
['acd3f','rt5gh8','5ty7e']    ['I am cool','I am not cool','ok_sir']
['rt5gh8','t67ui']            ['I am not cool','no_sir']
```

I am trying the below code -

```
df1['value_names'] = df1['values'].replace(df2.set_index('0')['1'].dropna())
```

It doesn't seem to work and gives me an error -

```
KeyError: '1'
```

Note:
Basically, what I had before instead of df2 was a list with mapping. I converted that to data frame df2 and these column names "0" and "1" in df2 are automatically assigned.

Comment: Looks to me the column is not `'1'`, but `1`...

Comment: Basically, what I had before instead of df2 was a list with mapping. I converted that to data frame df2 and these column names are automatically assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary (`mapping`) of keys to their mapped values from `df2` (Column `0` are the keys and Column `1` are their corresponding values.

Then used a nested list comprehension to look up the values and append it to `df1` using `assign`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'values': [['acd3f','rt5gh8','5ty7e'], ['rt5gh8','t67ui']]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({0: ['acd3f', 'rt5gh8', '5ty7e', 't67ui'], 
                    1: ["I am cool", "I am not cool", "ok_sir", "no_sir"]})

mapping = {k: v for k, v in zip(df2[0], df2[1])}

>>> df1.assign(value_names=[[mapping.get(val) for val in sublist] 
                            for sublist in df1['values'] ])
                   values                         value_names
0  [acd3f, rt5gh8, 5ty7e]  [I am cool, I am not cool, ok_sir]
1         [rt5gh8, t67ui]             [I am not cool, no_sir]
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ One man's simplification is another's complication... I chose the mapping method `{k: v for k, v in zip(df2[0], df2[1])}` because it is more explicit in terms of the columns used for keys and those used for values and because it would also work if the dataframe had more columns than the two listed.  I prefer nested list comprehension, but the second method you suggest should work equally well.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version (imo) of Alexander's code:

```
In [484]: mapping = dict(df2.values[:, :2])

In [485]: df1.assign(value_names=df1['values'].apply(lambda x: [mapping[k] for k in x]))
Out[485]: 
                   values                         value_names
0  [acd3f, rt5gh8, 5ty7e]  [I am cool, I am not cool, ok_sir]
1         [rt5gh8, t67ui]             [I am not cool, no_sir]
```

You can create a mapping from the 2D `np` array retrieved using `df2.values`.

Then, use `df.assign` to create the `value_names` list.